# AngularJS and Windows 8 route error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a HTML5/JS/CSS3 App with angularJS on Windows 8.1 with visual studio 2012. I'm currently stuck on sending over parameters to other views.

When googleing I see several examples using `<a href="#/page/{{:pageId}}">link</a>` When I do this in my Windows 8 application and clicking on the link I am getting the following error.

> No Apps are installed to open this type of link (unsafe)

When I put the `{{:pageId}}` code between the A tags it shows its ID.

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/", { templateUrl: "views/home.html" })
        .when("/page/:pageId", { templateUrl: "views/page.html" })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
}]);
```

What is a solution to solve this problem?

--update--

I have done some more debugging. 
In the browser it's all working fine.
In visual studio I have found the following:

```
<a class="ng-binding" href="unsafe:ms-appx://3595d292-0235-47cd-8db7-cb3019f29114/www/index.html#/page/1" data-ng-href="#/page/1">Select</a>
```

Looks like VS is adding some code. In the source I haven't include the href item

I have changed the link and all seems fine, also the correct variable is loaded only VS keeps adding 'unsafe:' at the frond of the link.

Comment: The `{{:pageId}}` binding will be looking for a property called `pageId` on your controller's `$scope` object.  Do you have that property in your controller?  If not, when Angular evaluates the `{{:pageId}}` expression, it will find out that pageId is undefined and will change your link to `href="#/page/"`, which you don't have a route defined for that...

Comment: What is the url in your browser? Is it file:// or http://?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. Because it's all HTML5 and JS I tested it in the browser and there it works perfect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem solved!

seems like the ms-appx that is being added by ms causes the problem. This is being resolved by addeing this following code.

AngularJS 1.2

```
app.config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|ms-appx):/);
}]);
```

For 1.1.x and 1.0.x, use urlSanitizationWhitelist.

If you use PhoneGap, remember to add file besides https?, otherwise, links will not work.

Comment: Wow great find, I was unable to get a good debugging environment so I didn't know that it was also appending ms-appx.

Comment: awesome.. this made my day for the windows target of our cordova project