# Windows 8 and href

Tags: angularjs, windows-store-apps, multi-device-hybrid-apps, ngroute

I am trying to convert an AngularJS web app to a multi device app.

On the web application I used the ngRoute.
Basically something like this

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/Home',
          {
              controller: 'homeCtr',
              templateUrl: '/scripts/app/modules/home/home.html' 

          })
```

}]);

and in the index html page a simple href and the ngView like below:

```
<a ng-href="#/Home">Go to Home</a>
<div data-ng-view="">

</div>
```

If I run the application in Ripple for android it works like a charm, but on Windows or Windows ARM  doesn't work at all!
Seems it doesn't know how to interpret the # on the link.

How can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590818/angularjs-and-windows-8-route-error)

Comment: Hi Avani, yes eventually I found it and I answered to my post by myself just 30 seconds before your comment! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590818/angularjs-and-windows-8-route-error) and this [article](http://www.stephenpauladams.com/articles/angularjs-cordova-windows-phone-quirk/) as well!

Basically the problem is that when the app is published as Win App, the href is rendered with a prefix
like 'unsafe:ms-appx'.

To let it works correctly, is enough just to add this config

```
app.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|ghttps?|ms-appx|x-wmapp0):/);}]);
```

Also, keep in mind that when you configure a templateUrl on **$routeProvider**, you cannot start your url with "/" if you want to that the application works fine in Windows too (I used to set my template url like **"/app/views/myView.html"** to be sure that the path starts from root, ***but this approach seems not working for windows app***).

Thanks!