# Angular Phonegap windows phone

Tags: angularjs, windows-phone, phonegap-build

I'm getting
"Search for an app in the app store?"
when clicking on ng-hrefs.

I've tried
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);

but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this post

http://www.stephenpauladams.com/articles/angularjs-cordova-windows-phone-quirk/

[AngularJS and Windows 8 route error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590818/angularjs-and-windows-8-route-error)

windows phone appends ms-appx.. lol so this is what you do

```
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|ghttps?|ms-appx|x-wmapp0):/);
```